# Update bios for Lenovo with AMD Ryzen 5 3500u laptop

Tags: laptop, bios, integrated-graphics

Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14ADA05
AMD Ryzen 5 3500U
8GB DDR4
SSD 256GB
AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics
Windows 10 pro 21H1

I would like to change in the bios the option for the integrated graphics memory from 2GB to 1GB. The laptop i just bought has the outdated bios version resulting in the lack of this option.
My question for the owners of this laptop is if i update to the latest bios version , this option to change the amount of ram memory of the integrated graphics will appear in settings.
I didn't update the bios because the laptop is under warranty and i don't want to cause possible damage. I know it's an easy way to update the bios but if this setting will not appear after update i want to wait till the new version of bios for windows 11.

Comment: Updating BIOS will NOT void your warranty. In fact: if a manufacturer supplied bios-update causes problems you have reason to make a  warranty claim. So it is probably better to update now while you are still under warranty. And as Bios updates usually provide bug-fixes and/or improve stability and/or add functionality (e.g support newer CPU's) it is usually a good idea to update is there is an update. P.S. There is no guarantee there will be a bios update for Windows 11. Many vendors will not issue one because Windows 11 will in most cases work fine with the exisiting bios.

Comment: Ok . I will update the bios.

Comment: Use the Lenovo Software Update app to update BIOS. That works on my Lenovo machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the latest bios version but there is no option to change the vram memory.
In Amd Radeon software it shows me that Vega 8 graphics has 2 gb ram memory and also there is no option to modify it.
I think that with this laptop model i can't change the integrated graphics memory.

The laptop with Amd Ryzen 5 5500U has this option in bios to change the vram.
I know it's another integrated graphics but why was it possible to put this option in the bios and not for Ryzen 3500U.

Comment: There is a possibility that at the next bios update to introduce this option?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple.

The BIOS probably has an option to update bios from usb stick, or a tool from lenovo to update the bios from inside windows

Also, the only risk from flashing your bios is corrupting it, which will leave your pc in an unbootable state.

Usually re-flasing/replacing the chip comes under warranty

If i misunderstood your question, sorry.